# Prevent multiple instances of NodeJS handling Redis PubSub event

Tags: node.js, redis, publish-subscribe

I have an interesting conundrum; I use Redis PubSub pattern to emit events within my network of NodeJS microservices.  I moved away from RabbitMQ because I needed the messages to be multi-cast, so that multiple microservices could receive and handle the same event. So if I emit a LOGOUT event, both the UserService and the WebSocketService should hear it.

This worked fine until my client deployed in an environment in which multiple instances of each microservice run.  Now, given 3 instances of a UserService, all instances connect to Redis and they all receive and handle the LOGOUT event, which is bad.

So on one hand I need the distinct microservices to hear the event, but on the other I need to prevent the duplicate copies of the same microservice from all handling the event. Rock, meet hard place.

My best thinking so far is a bit hacky, but something like:

1. Instead of raising events, write to the Redis cache a list of events
2. The UserService and WebSocketService could read that list once every 3 seconds and check for new events that need handling
3. When a relevant event is found, UserService would add its "name" to the list of services that is handling the event
4. When WebSocketService sees the event, it will still be able to handle it and add its "name" to the handlers list
5. When a duplicate instance of UserService sees the event, it will see its "name" already in the list of handlers and ignore that event

I don't love this solution because the list will be ever-growing in memory rather than in a transient message.  Also I'll have to start adding code to manage which events have already been checked; otherwise every cycle, the whole list would have to be parsed again by all instances of all services.

Ideas welcome.

Answer (score 6):

[Redis streams](https://redis.io/topics/streams-intro) seems to be helpful for your use case. Did you check that?.

We can have multiple consumers groups. Like pub/sub, Each consumer group is expected to receive the message from the stream. (Here stream is like pub/sub channel/topic). However, when there are multiple nodes within a consumer group, only one node will process the event. Not all. Node can acknowledge the message it has processed.

- Upon restart, nodes will not process already delivered message
- Stream will keep on growing. We can trim based on size. We can keep the latest N elements.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for sharing.  This seems so far like a native way to address the problem

Answer (score 1):

For the scenario you described I would use both the pattern: an events queue (or more specifically an events queue for each cluster of consumers) implemented with [redlock](https://redis.io/topics/distlock) **and** the PubSub pattern to alert all the consumers that a new event is ready to be consumed. Respect to your proposed solution this should be a bit more reactive because there is no polling but the access to the queue(s) is event driven.

Comment: Would you get a bit more specific please?  Specifically the emitter should not know whom the message is for, so when he emits and all duplicate instances of the same microservice receive the event, what happens?  Who queues it up?

Comment: The emitter should do both the operations @BeetleJuice . First enqueue the event in the queue (or in the queues: one for the UserService cluster and one for the WebSocketService cluster), then Pub the event. All consumers will receive the event: for each cluster, the first able to dequeue the event from its secific queue (probably the one under the lower workload) will process it.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  The Redis Streams suggestion from user vins seems like a more natural solution to the problem statement

Answer (score 0):

Upon being notified, consume the list of events on Redis using [LPOP](https://redis.io/commands/lpop) and only act if there's actually something on that list.

This will both cleanup the event list and guarantee that only one consumer will actually execute an action.

Comment: Thanks; I think you misunderstood.  I don't want to guarantee a single handler per event.  In my example above, I want both UserService and WebSocketService to independently handle the event.  What I want to guarantee is that duplicate instances of UserService do not handle the event (I have multiple processes of the same service running).  Only one instance of UserService and one instance of WebSocketService should handle the event.

Comment: ok. On top of my mind I would then have the 2 different services consume 2 dirrerent lists of events. I think that acting upon the notification of Pub/Sub is an anti-pattern and consumer should act on Events, and the Pub/Sub is just there to prevent clients from polling the lists and also react faster.

Answer (score 0):

**Hey I faced the same issue after running servers on multiple instances.**

- In my case I used mongodb as database so whenever I received a
  keySpace notification I created a write-lock to my db for that
  particular subscription.

> So I created a write-lock itself.Whenever I get the subscription of
> that particular key that you've subscribed I incremented the key
> regarding that particular document by 1. And by updating I get
> nModified:1 in my case once it got modified by creating some
> conditions accordingly.
>
> So once the server sends multiple request by creating some conditions
> I managed to enter that condition and update that key and once and
> perform whatever task I wanted too.

You can do the same by creating your own write-lock.

**Hail Coding**